# Output Zoom sound (all participants) directly to a browser in macOS Ventura

Tags: google-chrome, audio, zoom-meeting, macos-ventura

Running macOS 13.3 (22E252), and using Chrome Version 112.0.5615.49 (Official Build) (arm64), but it should work in other browser as well.

• The goal: outputing (or channelling) the sound of Zoom meetings (all participants including myself) in Chrome so 1) it can be picked up (recorded) by Microsoft Word 365 running in Chrome and 2) the audio output can be automatically transcribed (as opposed to recording a file first, then uploading the file to Microsoft 365 for transcription).

I got half-way there: i.e. it works, but I’m missing one piece.

What I tried so far:

1. Downloaded Black Hole
2. in macOS Audio MIDI Setup (found in Utilities), created a Multi-Output Device
3. That device use my external headphone (which I use while on Zoom) and BlackHole 2ch
4. In the Sound pane of macOS System Settings > Output > I selected the agregate device (created in Audio MIDI setup)
5. In Zoom, for speaker, I selected “same as system” i.e. the agregate device
6. In Chrome > Setting > Privacy and Security > Site settings > Microphone > and selected BlackHole 2ch (Virtual) as the microphone Chrome is allowed to use
7. Made sure Microsoft (the 365 website) is allowed to use the microphone

... and this actually works. You can get a transcription of all participants through feeding the audio from Zoom, via Balck Hole and Chrome, into Microsoft 365 online. No need to record anything in Zoom itself. No need to record video in OBS either.

With one caveat, hence this question: I can’t get to record *my* microphone, so anything I say is not transcribed, despite me adding the microphone to the Multi-Output Device (I use a Yeti). I must be missing a step. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your mic, going to Zoom, is not included in Zoom's output. You need to sniff it before it hits Zoom & send it directly to 'somewhere down the chain', Chrome or MS. I'm not sure whether BlackHole can do this. tbh, I've never used it, though it looks very similar to the old Soundflower in how it routes. Soundflower used to have an inter-app 'extra', Flowerbed, that was abandoned long ago & idk if BH can do it either. I'd try the demos of Rogue Amoeba's [Audio Hijack](https://rogueamoeba.com/audiohijack/) and/or [Loopback](https://rogueamoeba.com/loopback/) [not cheap] & see if they can do it.

Comment: Part of the issue is being able to route an out to an in somewhere. That's where it gets to be a fight. Once you start looking at Hijack, you'll be able to see graphically, what I mean & where an app/device is not going to play ball. BTW… usually, if Rogue Amaoeba can't do it, you can consider it can't be done. They're top in this game, by a way. [They started from Soundflower, inherited from Cycling'74 way back]

Comment: Thank you very much Tetsujin: that’s useful info, especially the apps, which I might end up trying. I thought that adding the Yeti mic to the to the multi-output group would wrap both the output from Zoom and the output from the mic into Balck Hole virtual mic, but so far no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s possible to achieve the above using only the free app BlackHole. The thing missing in my initial setup was an Agreggate Device, which is configured in macOS Audio MIDI setup. To summarize:

**1) in Audi MIDI Setup:**

a) Create a Multi Output Device which uses: **(a1)** the source where you hear the sound (either built-in speaker or external headphone); **(a2)** BlackHole (the 2ch version is enough), and **(a3)** ZoomAudioDevice. The primary device is BlackHole, and drift correction is only applied to the source of the sound (built-in speaker or ext. headphones) and ZoomAudioDevice.

b) Create an Aggregate Device which uses: **(b1)** whatever you use as mic; **(b2)** BlackHole; **(b3)** the source where you hear the sound (either built-in speaker or external headphone); and **(b4)** ZoomAudioDevice. The Clock Source is the mic, and drift correction is applied to BlackHole and the ZoomAudioDevice.

**2) in macOS System Settings > Sound:**

a) For the input, select BlackHole

b) For the output, also select BlackHole

**3) In Zoom > Preferences > Audio**

a) Speaker: select your BlackHole Multi-Output Device

b) Mic: select your BlackHole Aggregate Device

**4) In Chrome** > Settings... > Privacy and security > Site settings > Microphone > select your BackHole Aggregate device.

**5) Finally, in Microsoft Word** (the online version, part of 365), make sure you are signed-in. In the tool bar, check for “Dictate” (towards the right), click on the downward arrow just next to it, then on “Transcribe”. Look for a cog wheel (or gear) icon, click on it, and make sure the same BlackHole Aggregate device is selected.

With this configuration, the voices of all participants, including yourself, can be captured and transcribed directly in Microsoft Word while running a Zoom meeting.